# Why Doesn't IOS Core BLuetooth Respect Communication Rate

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am writing a Core Bluetooth App for IOS.  It is connecting to a TI device With custom firmware.  The firmware developer developed it to publish data 12 times a second.  I am using the Notify Property to get the data, but it seems that we are grabbing the data 30 times per second.  This is causing extra power consumption, and for specific reasons, I can't pull at my own rate I need to pull at the rate of the device is publishing.

The firmware developer created a Windows Application that doesn't have this problem without having a hard coded Read Rate.  So it is On me to find the issue.
Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: How are you reading the data?  Simply by getting calls to `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` ? You aren't issuing any calls to `readValueForCharacteristic`?

Comment: No I am not using readValueForCharacteristic The firmware dev thinks is when twe connect the device we need to set a Minimum Connection Interval but I can't see where to set that in Core Bluetooth

Comment: You don't have any control over those parameters in core Bluetooth. You should get a single call to the delegate method each time the peripheral issues a notify on the property. If you are getting more than 1 call per notify then you have some issue in your code. Do you only have a single instance of CBCentralManager?

Answer (score 0):

For what you are describing, on your system the Swift side is just receiving notifications, so there is no control over the rate that *your device* is using to update that specific characteristic.

But, some devices may have a command on their own high level protocol to set the advertising interval. That's completely up to the manufacturer. If you think that the system is advertising at a different rate with that Windows app that you have mentioned, I would suggest to take a look to see if there is any initialization code that the app may be doing when it starts (thus setting the rate). But for that you will need the Windows app's source code, or at least the manufacturer's documentation about your device's protocol (if any).

Also, are you really sure that the updating rate when the device is connected to the Windows app is really lower than the one you are experimenting when connected your iOS app? How are you measuring that?